# search array ID with 2 tables relacional with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to make the codes and nothing success.
I would like some help and if some code is missing.
If I type the input which is the brand name (from REGISTER table) and get the result of the product type element (TYPE from Product List table).

```js
$(btn_search).click(function() {
  var search = $("search").val();
  var data = "op=list of product&name=" + search;
  $.get('prod.php', data, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var line = "";
    $.each(result.data, function(i, item) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
        if (item !== 0) {
          $row = $(this);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary" id="btn_search">SEARCH</button>

<table class="tabela resultados">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME OF PRODUTS:</td>
      <td>BRAND:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
public function list of product
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

$data = q_pdo("SELECT prod.id, prod.name, prod.description, prod.type,reg.id as registrationid, reg.brand as namebrand
FROM List Of Product 
JOIN IN reg.id as registrationid, reg.brand as namebrand");

public function registration
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

$data = q_pdo("SELECT reg.id  reg.brand, reg.qtde FROM Registration");
```

Comment: I removed the script tags from your script code and added jQuery. Please fix the errors that now appear so we can see the issue. Ideally you'll mock the ajax call so it works.

Comment: You search button does not have value tag defined define it, additionally you are getting the response object from server where as trying to go through result object check that out. thirdly data in ajax call is what you sending to prod.php and its missing leading ? to create proper url

Comment: There should not be PHP code in a demo snippet. It can't run there. Add it as a separate code block if you like, but it's probably not relevant to a jQuery question.